# Query on Select System Call

Tags: c, sockets

select() is defined as :

```
int select(int nfds, fd_set *readfds, fd_set *writefds, fd_set *errorfds, struct timeval *timeout);
```

*nfds* represents the highest file descriptor in all given sets plus one. I would like to know why is this data required for select() when the fd_set information is available.

If the FDs in the set are say, 4, 8, 9 ,the value of *nfds* would be 10. Would select() moniter fds 9,8,7,6,5,4 ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The catch is that fd_set is not really a "set" in the way you're thinking. The behind-the-scenes detail is that the implementation of an fd_set is just an integer that is used as a bitfield. In other words, executing

```
fd_set foo;
FD_CLEAR(&foo);
FD_SET(&foo, 3);
```

Sets foo to decimal value 8  - it sets the fourth-least-singificant bit to 1 (remember that 0 is a valid descriptor).

```
FD_SET(&foo, 3);
```

is equivalent to

```
foo |= (1 << 3);
```

So in order for select to work right, it needs to know which bits of the fd_set are bits that you care about. Otherwise there would be no way for it to tell a zero bit that is "in" the set but set to false from a zero bit that is "not in" the set.

In your example, a fd_set with 4, 8, and 9 set and n = 10 is interpreted as "A set with 10 entries (fds 0-9). Entries 4, 8, and 9 are true (monitor them). Entries 1,2,3,5,6,7 are false (don't monitor them). Any fd value greater than 9 is simply not in the set period."

Comment: But number of bits in int is 32, but how can it monitor any fd with a value greater than 31

Comment: can someone answer this comment ?

Comment: @Shishir:  Posix defines `fd_set` to be a struct.  The internals are implementation defined, but a popular implementation is for the struct to contain an array of longs with enough bits in the array to cover all possible fd's.  This works because Posix also requires `open` to return "the lowest numbered unused file descriptor".  So you won't exceed the range of the array unless you have FD_SETSIZE files open. http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007904975/basedefs/sys/select.h.html

Comment: @Shishir: actually FD_SET(&foo, 3) is equivalent to foo |= (1 << 3 % NFDBITS); where NFDBITS may be 32 or 64 based on implementation.

Comment: Shouldn't it be `FD_SET(3, &foo)`?

Answer (score 0):

Select monitors those FDs which you have enabled using the FD_SET macro. If you do not enable any FD for monitoring, select() does not monitor any.

"nfds" is definitely redundant, but it is part of the select() interface, so you need to use it :)

Anyway, if you have {4, 8, 9} in the set, you set nfds to 10 (as you mentioned), and select() will only monitor the three FDs 4, 8 and 9.

Answer (score 0):

It's probably an optimization so that `select` doesn't have to walk through the whole `fd_set` to find out which descriptors are actually used. Without that parameter, `select` would always need to look at the whole set to find which descriptors are actually used in the call, with the parameter, some of that work can be omitted.