# How to use the select() function in socket programming?

Tags: select, sockets, file-descriptor

The prototype is:

```
int select (int nfds,
            fd_set *read-fds,
            fd_set *write-fds,
            fd_set *except-fds,
            struct timeval *timeout);
```

I've been struggling to understand this function for quite some time. My question is, if it checks all the file descriptors from 0 to nfds-1, and will modify the read-fds, write-fds and except-fds when return, why do I need to use FD_SET to add file descriptors to the set at the begining, it will check all the file descriptors anyway, or not?

Comment: This is that `select` that was broken? :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It won't check from 0 to `nfds`-1. The first argument just provides an upper bound on how large, numerically, the file descriptors used are. This is because the set itself might be represented as a bitvector, without a way to know how many bits are actually used. Specifying this as a separate argument helps `select()` avoid checking file descriptors that are not in use.

Also, a descriptor that is not in e.g. the read set when you call `select()` is not being checked at all, so it cannot appear in the set when the call returns, either.

Answer (score 0):

I once had the same doubt as yours. You can look at following question and answers:

[Query on Select System Call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/644370/query-on-select-system-call)